# TintMCE - Change text font size after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to change the size of the selected text after I click the font button in `Change Font`:
But I it doesn't change after using the line :

`editor.execCommand("fontSize", false, e.data.source)`

Here is the code with its fiddle :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "wrapselection | code | insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image",
    setup: function (editor) {
       editor.addButton('wrapselection', {
          text: 'Change Font',
          icon: false,
          onclick: function () {


                    editor.windowManager.open({
                    title: 'Enter Font Size',
                    body: [
                        {type: 'textbox', name: 'source', label: 'Font Size'}
                    ],
                    onsubmit: function(e) {
                        alert(e.data.source);
                        editor.focus();
                        editor.execCommand("fontSize", false, e.data.source);

                    }
                });


          }
       });
    }

});
</script>

<form method="post" action="dump.php">
    <textarea name="content">This is content in the editor</textarea>
</form>
```

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/a7gaab

How can I change the font size AFTER the user clicked his size ?

Answer (score 1):

Just add below line of code after your alert message

```
editor.getBody().style.fontSize = e.data.source + 'px';
```

Updated code

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/b7gaab